# SQL: Prevent data from displaying with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

is their any way or a query to prevent data from displaying if it has same incident_id and the pnt_id is NULL using

[image]

in my attached image. the highlighted data must not be displayed

is it possible? if so. can anyone help me.? and Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name its PHPMyAdmin( XAMMP )

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name and if may i ask? whats about the link u just commented?.

Comment: it's a meta question. Go through that link and post what you have tried so far

Comment: Sorry i don't know how meta.SO works and his link directed me to Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question? [duplicate] and i dont know if that help me with my question

Comment: Short version - replace images with text (select text and press ctrl+k in order to keep the format)

Comment: does anyone know the answer?. plss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
 SELECT respond_id, incident_id, pnt_id FROM TBL 
 WHERE pnt_id IS NOT NULL
 UNION
 SELECT respond_id, incident_id, pnt_id FROM TBL
 WHERE incident_id in (SELECT distinct(incident_id) 
                       FROM TBL 
                       GROUP BY incident_id 
                       HAVING count(id) = 1);
```

The first part of the union will get all the not null pnt_ids
and the second part will get all the records that may be null but go in the result.

Union merges the two results eliminating duplicates

Comment: i got an error `Unknown column 'pnt_id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: are you sure that the names of the columns you posted are correct?
I used tbl as table name because you didn't provide the name of the table

Comment: dude sorry this is the error  now . `Unknown column 'respond_id' in 'having clause'`.. i made a mistake in the table name

Comment: sorry again dude. demn. i made a mistake again in the second table. now this is the error`#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns ` im really sorry.

Comment: I edited the answer and cited the column names respectively instead of using *

Comment: but will this work if i have left joins?. coz both pnt_id and inc_id are foreign keys to another table.